# How to find a random number between 2 numbers

Tags: python, random

I am making a program that asks for 2 random numbers and prints a random integer between the 2 numbers that have been asked for. My code works except for the times where I give 2 consecutive numbers, it won't print a decimal/float.

```
import random

def bound():
    print("Give me a number")
    s = input()
    print("Give me another number")
    x = input()
    w = random.randint(int(s),int(x))
    if w == s:
        None
    if w == x:
        None
    else:
        print(w)
bound()
```

Comment: It is a ```randint``` which means ```random integer```

Comment: if you want to get random float numbers you should use: `random.uniform(int(s),int(x))` instead `random.randint()`

Comment: What is the nonsense with `if w == s: None`?  If you don't want the two numbers included in the random range, then you need to change the range.  What you have now makes no sense.  And right now, your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Really, your specification is unclear, and that's the major cause of confusion.  You said "print a random integer between the 2 numbers".  If you want a random integer, then why would you ever expect a float?  If you want a number between two numbers but EXCLUDING the endpoints, then there ARE no integers between 2 and 3.  You need to clarify the question before we can give you sensible answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're so close! Just replace `randint` with `uniform`:

```
def bound():
    print("Give me a number")
    s = input()
    print("Give me another number")
    x = input()
    w = random.uniform(int(s),int(x))
    if w == s:
        None
    if w == x:
        None
    else:
        print(w)
bound()
```

`randint` returns an integer, whereas `uniform` returns a random float from between the numbers passed.

Comment: The conditions w==s and w==x are never met since w is a float and x and s are strings.  Furthermore the None by itself doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.uniform` for 2 consecutive numbers and normal `random.randint` for non consecutive numbers. `randint` is basically `random integer`: **`rand`**`om` and **`int`**`eger`. It basically fetches integers from a given *range*.

```
def bound():
    print("Give me a number")
    s = input()
    print("Give me another number")
    x = input()
    w = random.uniform(int(s),int(x))
    print(w)
    
bound()
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, does it?  You either want an integer or you want a float.  I know the poster didn't specify, but I'm not sure this answer really helps.

Answer (score 0):

`randint` generates integer value, to get the decimal value you can use `uniform`.

**Try this**

```
def bound():
    print("Give me a number")
    s = input()
    print("Give me another number")
    x = input()
    if int(s)+1 == int(x):                 # check for continuity
        w = random.uniform(int(s),int(x))
    else:
        w = random.randint(int(s),int(x))
    if w == s:
        None
    if w == x:
        None
    else:
        print(w)
bound()
```

This will return a integer value if numbers are not continuous and a float value if they are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is unclear.  In my mind, if I say "pick a number between 1 and 4", then the possible answers are 1, 2, 3, or 4.  In that case:

```
def bound():
    x = int(input("Enter lower bound:"))
    y = int(input("Enter upper bound:"))
    return random.randint(x,y)
```

If you want a real number between 1 and 4 (where 2.773 is a valid answer), then you want:

```
def bound():
    x = int(input("Enter lower bound:"))
    y = int(input("Enter upper bound:"))
    return random.uniform(x,y)
```

If you want an integer between the two endpoints but excluding the two endpoints, which seems silly, then you want:

```
def bound():
    x = int(input("Enter lower bound:"))
    y = int(input("Enter upper bound:"))
    if abs(y-x) <= 1:
        print("There are no integers between",x,"and",y)
        return None
    else:
        return random.randint(x+1,y-1)
```